# Python - Summarizing rows in grouped totals per column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am stuck with a problem:

I have a table with many rows and columns like this (just more rows and columns):

Pizza consumption:

df =

```
+------------------------------------------------------+
|      Name        Day 1 | Day 2 | Day 3 | Day 4 |Day 5|
+------------------------------------------------------+
| Michelangelo   |  1    |   5   |   2   |  1    |   5 |
| Michelangelo   |  4    |   2   |   3   |  1    |   5 |
| Donatello      |  2    |   1   |   1   |  8    |   2 |
| Leonardo       |  3    |   2   |   4   |  2    |   1 |
| Michelangelo   |  3    |   1   |   2   |  1    |   5 |
| Raphael        |  2    |   2   |   3   |  1    |   3 |
| Michelangelo   |  4    |   3   |   1   |  1    |   5 |
+------------------------------------------------------+
```

I want to get a table with the daily totals for each turtle like this:

df_total =

```
+-------------------------------------------------------+
|      Name        Day 1 | Day 2 | Day 3 | Day 4 | Day 5|
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| Michelangelo   |  13   |   11  |   8   |  4    |   20 |
| Donatello      |  2    |   1   |   1   |  8    |   2  |
| Leonardo       |  3    |   2   |   4   |  2    |   1  |
| Raphael        |  2    |   2   |   3   |  1    |   3  |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

As I did not want the names to become indices I tried (among many other things):

```
df_total = df.groupby(['Name'], axis = 0).sum().reset_index()
```

I got one summarizing row with every field in the selection summed in one giant sum in each column of the row. That would be 56 Pizzas each day for Michelangelo.

Thank you for looking at it!

Comment: `df.groupby('Name', as_index=False).sum()`

Comment: Yeah, `axis=0` means **row-wise** sum - which is not what you want!

Comment: Double-checking my attempt, I found that it would work with test-data like this as well. However, the given solutions are better. With my original data, they also fail, so it is my data that brings the problem in. I will find out and comment.

Comment: @val_to_many Hey, just to know, could you tell me why did you accept the answer from Keyur Togadiya instead of [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63122063/13676202), when I answered first and we have the same... I hope I'm not being rude, I just don't understand why

Comment: @MrNobody33 - I believe it was the first answer and although yours was more detailed, I thought it is fair to grab the first one. Thinking about it ... you are right. It should be the one that really helped. Changed it ;)

Comment: No worries, thanks for changing it :) @val_to_many . Just to clarify: yes you should accept the answer that helped you the most, but in this case, we both had the same solution, maybe one better explained than the other, the difference was who answered first, that in fact it was me (you can check it with the *oldest* button), and that was the reason of my complaint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `pd.DataFrame.groupby.sum` without the parameter `axis=0`(row-wise):

```
df=df.groupby('Name',as_index=False).sum()
```

Output:

```
df
           Name  Day 1  Day 2  Day 3  Day 4  Day 5
0     Donatello      2      1      1      8      2
1      Leonardo      3      2      4      2      1
2  Michelangelo     12     11      8      4     20
3       Raphael      2      2      3      1      3
```

And IIUC, you can use `pd.DataFrame.sum` to get the total sum, of each row(`axis=1`):

```
df['total']=df.sum(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
df
           Name  Day 1  Day 2  Day 3  Day 4  Day 5  total
0     Donatello      2      1      1      8      2     14
1      Leonardo      3      2      4      2      1     12
2  Michelangelo     12     11      8      4     20     55
3       Raphael      2      2      3      1      3     11
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, `df.groupby(['Name'], as_index=False).sum()`